# PHP Database Searchform SQL Trouble

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, join

I have three tables in my database; ACTOR_DETAIL, MOVIE_ACTOR, and MOVIE_TITLE. Entries from each table include:

For ACTOR_DETAIL (4 fields = actor sequence number, name, birthday, gender):

> (ACTOR_SEQUENCE_NB) (NAME) (BIRTHDAY) (GENDER)
>
> 001 John 1/1/1964 Male
>
> 002 Dave 2/2/1980 Male
>
> 003 Jane 3/3/1975 Female

For MOVIE_TITLE (3 Fields = MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB, MOVIE TITLE, YEAR)

> SSN Name City
>
> 001 MovieTitleA 1987
>
> 002 MovieTitleB 2008
>
> 003 MovieTitleC 2014

and the last table, MOVIE_ACTOR, brings the two together (3 fields = MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB, ACTOR_SEQUENCE_NB, CHARACTER_PLAYED)

> WSN SSN Pay
>
> 001 003 The Protagonist (John, who was in MovieTitleC, played the Protagonist)
>
> 003 001 The Antagonist (Jane, who was in MovieTitleA, played the Antagonist)
>
> 002 003 The Anti-Hero (Dave, who played in MovieTitleC, played the Anti-Hero)

I am currently making a search form, that will allow users to input the name of the Worker. The search form will then take the input name, match it with the corresponding WSN, take the WSN and match it with the corresponding SSN, take the SSN, then match it with the corresponding Store Name and City, then output that information (The Store Name and City from the STORE_NAME table).

In my document titled: searchform.html, this is the snippet that makes the form:

`<html>`
`<head>`

```
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff>

<h2>Search</h2>

<form name="search" method="post" action="searchform.php">  

Name of Actor: <input type="text" name="find1" />

<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" /> 

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

and here is my php document:

```
<?php

include "config.php";

echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2><p>";

if(isset($_POST['search']))            
{
$find1 =$_POST['find1'];
$find2 =$_POST['find2'];
$field =$_POST['field'];
}

// We perform a bit of filtering
$find1 = strtoupper($find1);
$find1 = strip_tags($find1);
$find1 = trim ($find1);

$find2 = strtoupper($find2);
$find2 = strip_tags($find2);
$find2 = trim ($find2);

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
$iname = mysql_query("select ACTOR_DETAIL.ACTOR_SEQUENCE_NB, MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB.MOVIE_TITLE, MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB.YEAR_FILMED
from MOVIE_ACTOR join
     ACTOR_DETAIL 
     on MOVIE_ACTOR.ACTOR_SEQUENCE_NB = ACTOR_DETAIL.ACTOR_SEQUENCE_NB join
     MOVIE_TITLE 
     on MOVIE_ACTOR.MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB = MOVIE_TITLE.MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB
where ACTOR_DETAIL.NAME = "$find1")

or die(mysql_error());

//And we display the results
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($iname ))
{
echo "<b>Movie Name:</b> " .$result['MOVIE_TITLE'];
echo "<br> ";
echo "<b>Year:</b> ".$result['YEAR_FILMED'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}

$anymatches = mysql_num_rows($iname);
if ($anymatches == 0)
{
echo "Sorry, but there aren't any movies with that combination of actors!<br><br>";
}

?>
```

I have ommitted the DB Connection, but I have confirmed that it works. My error appears to be with the SQL statement, but I'm not quite sure what it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you got any error generated in the script?

Comment: Yes. It's giving me "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/wmnation/public_html/actorchemistrysearch2.php on line 49" which is where ACTOR_DETAIL.NAME = "$find1" in the php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not escape your values in the query. One of the corrections should be..

```
$iname = mysql_query('select ACTOR_DETAIL.ACTOR_SEQUENCE_NB, MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB.MOVIE_TITLE, MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB.YEAR_FILMED
from MOVIE_ACTOR join
     ACTOR_DETAIL 
     on MOVIE_ACTOR.ACTOR_SEQUENCE_NB = ACTOR_DETAIL.ACTOR_SEQUENCE_NB join
     MOVIE_TITLE 
     on MOVIE_ACTOR.MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB = MOVIE_TITLE.MOVIE_SEQUENCE_NB
where ACTOR_DETAIL.NAME = "'.$find1.'"');
```

Also, it is highly unlikely that someone would search by EXACT same Actor name as you stored in the db. May be worth using %LIKE% or MATCH.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this and for the suggestion; I will be sure to do that, but for the time being, I'd like to fix this SQL statement as it is. I'm now getting the error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in /home/wmnation/public_html/actorchemistrysearch2.php on line 51", which would refer to the "or die" statement?

Comment: Have you put back your db connection ;)

Comment: I did. Could it be something else?

Comment: Well, without seeing it is impossible to debug. Isn't it?

Comment: true. can we at least confirm that the sql statement logic is correct as is? debugging the connection should be simple.

Comment: Sure. Use an echo to output the query as a string and die to terminate right after echo. Copy the sql output to phpmyadmin for validation.